# Forth expression arithmetic operations

Tags: forth, gforth

In *Java* it's possible to do the following:

```
int var = 5;
var += 2;
var -= 2;
var *= 2;
var /= 2;
```

Is it possible to do this in Forth?

```
variable var
3 var !
1 var +! //Increment
```

Is it possible to do the other operations like that in Forth? If not, any hints on how to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for decrementing with `-2 var +!`, those other operations are not built in.

You can do this:

```
: -! ( x addr -- )   swap negate swap +! ;
: *! ( x addr -- )   tuck @ * swap ! ;
: /! ( n addr -- )   tuck @ / swap ! ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental reason why this can't be done in Forth.
Let's have

> int var, var1 ;

and Jave code :

> 'var   =     var1    ;

Apart from the matter that Forth wants the tokens separated by spaces, Forth wants a word always do the same, independant of context.
In the Java code *var* is a left side and that means it must represent an address, where something is stored.
On the right hand side *var1* also represents an address. But Java magically fetches the content of the address! In Forth we don't deal in magic. We can't have it that *var* is now doing this and then doing that. 
The examples that you give are doable as long as you stay clear from the magic parts, as is explained in other answers.

[And of course Forth can also do magic. You could make an =-word that inspects whether the following word var is of type int and then fetches it. But that is not Forth, that is a Forth-implementation of Java.]